# How to connect outlets from UITableViewCell custom class to UILabels?

Tags: ios, swift3

I cannot seem to connect my outlets to UILabels in prototype cell on the storyboard.  I have ctrl-clicked on the UITableViewCell custom class in the document outline and it does not show my outlets where I was then hoping to drag to connect to the corresponding UILabels.  I have saved all my documents. Please can someone advise? - How would i do this programmatically if I cannot seem to do this via the storyboard?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, you have set the Class in the Identity Inspector?

Comment: please could you elaborate?

Comment: in storyboard, i click on ArticleCell(document outline) and in the identity inspector i set the class to "ArticleCell"

Comment: Sorry, thats what I meant. I have done the same and it works for me.

Comment: how would you do this programmatically?

Comment: There isn't a reason that shouldn't work. Try setting the module field under the class in the Identity Inspector. There should be an item named the same as your project. Maybe also try restarting Xcode?

Comment: @darrenallen For the ArticleCell class, in the identity inspector, under class (which is set to ArticleCell), the module is blank.

Comment: I have the similar issue before, first check have you set your class name. Last time I just restart my Xcode then it works, I know it  is not quite professional to say this, but Xcode sometimes is not normal and I don't know why